# FFMPEG won't configure for iPhone

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard, ffmpeg, configure

I have downloaded FFMPEG via svn, and put the gas-preprocessor into usr/local/bin. But, when I try to post the following code into terminal, it says: `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

This is the code:

> ./configure
>   --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc'
>   --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdk --enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=arm --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --disable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --disable-debug --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --extra-cflags='-arch armv6' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv6'

I am using Snow Leopard 10.6.1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the shell script you're trying to run has the wrong path for the hashbang at the top of the file (which is then reported correctly but ambiguously as a missing file).  Open up the configure script and check the path it's trying to run.

For example, take a look at the top of this configure script:

```
[on mymachine in directory sqsh-2.1.5]$ head -3 configure
#! /bin/sh
# Guess values for system-dependent variables and create Makefiles.
# Generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.
```

If for some reason `/bin/sh` does not exist, you'll get a file not found error.

Comment: If you're talking about the ffmpeg configure script, once opened it says its in the directory it IS is. Also, all the directories in code have the items in it. (eg. Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdkis the correct directory for the iPhone OS 3.1 sdk)

Answer (score 0):

The error is that it's not finding "configure" in the shell's current directory. What's your current working directory when you run this?

Comment: To expand on what NSR is asking, type `pwd`.  The result should be the same directory that ffmpeg has been placed into.  If not, then move there.

Comment: When I type pwn, it says the directory that ffmpeg is in, so no problem there.